# How to solve this basic thermodynamics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

This is just no question about an specific problem, but it rose while doing it, and it englobes some quality of problem solving in which different expressions can be used:

After i got this problem "Suppose that the temperature of one mole of gas is held fixed at 300 K, while the volume decreases at a rate of 2.0 litres/min. How quickly is the pressure of the gas increasing at the instant that the volume is 20 litres?" i started to think of strategies to solve it, since the problems states the value of tyhe derivative, i thought i should use differentiation in a basic way, thus the first thing i do is as follows:
I first thought to start with the ideal gass equation as:

$$PV = nRT$$ $$P'V + V'P = 0$$ $$P' = \frac{-V'P}{V}.$$
As I was told its not right; because there wasnt information explicitly shown(R,n) I decided to change a few things:
$$P = \frac{nRT}{V}$$
then:
$$P' = -\frac{nrTV'}{V^2}$$

So my questions are:

***Which one is right, if any?***
now i know that both answers yield the same result if one subtitutes p with the original result, but is this going to happen always? like isn't recursive?

**How to know how to proceed in further related problems?**
for there are problems in which differentiation comes into play , how am i supossed to know which is the right expression to differentiate?

Comment: The 2nd results is correct, and can be obtained from the first result by combining the first equation with the ideal gas law and eliminating P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both results are fine. You use different differentiation methods.

In your first approach, you use **implicit differentiation** which is why you end up with the pressure $P$ term. You'd need your ideal gas law equation to eliminate the $P$, as was pointed out in the comments by Chet Miller.

In your second approach, you differentiate as we would normally.

---

Consider the function $x^2 y + y = 1$. If you were to differentiate wrt $x$, then you could use implicit differentiation and end up with the following result:

$$2xy+x^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$$
in which case you would need to figure out your $y$ using the $x^2y+y=1$ equation.

You could alternatively explicitely solve for $y$ and get $$y=\dfrac1{1+x^2}\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\left(1+x^2\right)^{-2}.$$

Both approaches are fine and will give the same answer.